# Properties of Ultraviolet transmissions

Tags: optical

I am interested in expanding my experimentation on visible light communication to Ultraviolet. The properties of visible light are well known because we see it every day, and have receiver equipped permanently.

Through Amateur radio, I have learned about the spectrum below visible wavelength, but I want to dive into higher frequency transmissions.

What are some common properties of Ultraviolet light (UVA, UVB, UVC) when exposed to the atmosphere, and materials on Earth such as buildings, mountains, clouds, etc.?

How can I begin experimenting on a budget?

Answer (score 3):

Hams have played with visible light communication for ages.

Near-UV is pretty similar to visible light, so you could do the same sort of experiments, you can easily buy good LEDs and photodiodes in the UV range.

There might be less ambient noise than in the visible and IR ranges, but there will be more atmospheric absorption.

Do a bit of searching for amateur projects that cheap laser pointers, or LEDs, you'll find several of these. Also seatch for an LED-based data transmission project, that extends an ethernet cable over a free space optical link.